# does Wavelength of light change after striking bragg's plane?

Tags: braggs-law

When a photon particle falls on electron,  it will try to change the momentum of electron.  If the conduction band is partially unoccupied,  electron will move in the direction of change in momentum of photon. Due to this interatomic distance between the two electrons will reduce. Then,  the angle of incidence changes due to which the path difference changes, so that  wavelength changes.  But it doesn't happen practically. What can be the possible errors in my assumption? [image]

Answer (score 0):

The process you describe is known as [Compton scattering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compton_scattering). This does indeed happen in X-ray diffraction but the scattering probability is quite low so most of the X-rays are reflected with no frequency change.

The X-rays are mostly scattered by the core and valence electrons rather than electrons in conduction bands. This is simply because those electrons contribute most to the electron density. So most of the scattering comes from electrons that are bound to atoms and can't change their momentum. Compton scattering by conduction electrons does happen and can be measured, but it's usually too small to be significant in X-ray diffractomters.